# Looking for where addons are downloaded in files

Tags: garrys-mod

So I've been trying to use the Gmad extractor so I can make my own skins for Garrys Mod, but it says it can't find the addons and I need to put them in the same folder as it. But I don't know where to find them in the folders. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Your question is not really clear. Do you mean you cannot find the addons you downloaded for Garry's Mod in order to install them using the GMad Extractor? Or are you unable to install the addons using GMad because you cannot find them anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the GMA (Garry's Mod Addon) located in a few places:

- `addons` on the **Server** and are named similar to `ds_x.gma`

  - `garrysmod\cache\srcds` may also have some named `x.gma`

**You're probably looking for:**

- `garrysmod\downloads\server` on the **client** side and are named `x.gma`

Keep in mind if you're looking for certain addon that **x** is the steam workshop addon ID found after the ID parameter for example: `steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=123123` is `123123.gma`

Also, sometimes the files will be compressed and you'll need to extract them using an archive program like 7 Zip.

If you want to you can download the addons from a site, I suggest:
http://steamworkshopdownloader.io/

If you already have the files you can try GMoshUI:
https://github.com/FPtje/gmosh (this also helps to publish addons to the Steam)

Answer (score 0):

Give this [Steam community guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=252166735) a shot. I would recommend visiting the [Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/)  forums as the best resource on topics such as modding, support and discussion on apps like Garry's Mod. There are alternatives out there, but you'll likely have the best results at the Steam Community. Since Steam is the primary source for support, finding a decent alternative may be difficult. Hope the guide is what you're looking for. Your question is a *little* unclear, so I hope my answer is not too out-of-bounds for what you need. If this answer doesn't resolve your issue, try refining your question with more details.